# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

This integral seems to be an identity, since the antiderivative for $\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$ is somewhat cumbersome and the integrand has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$.

How do we evaluate this integral without resorting to a lookup table?

Comment: $x=\sin^2(u)$ seems to work nicely.

Comment: What makes you say that the antiderivative is particularly cumbersome? It's a rather straightforward computation, just let $t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$ for example.

Comment: The antiderivative as given by Wolfram|Alpha is pretty long in my opinion. Also, could you please clarify on what you mean by $t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$? Thanks.

Comment: If it is not a definite integral from outer space we have already covered one (almost) like it.

Comment: Sorry, I think it is. I tried searching for the integral before I posted but couldn't find that post. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Direct application of Beta function.

Comment: DanDan, that's ok. Experience helps in finding those. While the on-site search is bad for questions with complicated formulas, [TeX and Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1-x%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1) often help. Check it out!

Comment: @DanDan0101: I just mean integration by substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $$x=\sin^2t$$
$$\Longrightarrow dx=\sin 2t dt$$
$$\Longrightarrow \int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx=\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}\tan t \sin 2t dt$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}2\sin^2 t dt$$
$$=2×\frac{π}{4}=\frac{π}{2}$$
where the last step uses Walli's formula.
Hope it helps:)